# 'TraceEvents' undefined; assuming extern returning int

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, driver

I am trying to convert our existing driver code that is `using makefile` to `visual studio 2013 with MSBUILD`.

I have include all the header files and source code. The project is created as`KMDF driver`.

I have enabled`WPP tracing`, and inserted 3 parameters that we use

```
-km (in trace kernel-mode components --> Yes (-km) )  

-func (in functions to generate trace messages --> TraceEvents(LEVEL,FLAGS,MSG,...))  

-gen (in specify template file --> {km-WdfDefault.tpl}*.tmh)
```

When I build the project, error returns as:

```
'TraceEvents' undefined; assuming extern returning int
'DBG_PNP' : undeclared identifier
```

I am not sure why this is happening.
I think I am missing some steps.
Please direct me what I might have missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try starting a new project and selecting "Visual C++" -> "Windows Driver" -> "USB" -> "Kernel Mode Driver, USB (KMDF). This driver has WPP tracing set up and builds out of the box.

You should particularly take a look at the the Trace.h file included with the project and the comment block at the bottom; I know we've had problems when this was omitted.

The comment block looks like this:

```
// This comment block is scanned by the trace preprocessor to define our
// Trace function.
//
// begin_wpp config
// FUNC Trace{FLAG=MYDRIVER_ALL_INFO}(LEVEL, MSG, ...);
// FUNC TraceEvents(LEVEL, FLAGS, MSG, ...);
// end_wpp
```

Comment: This solves my problem. However, for unknown reason, I had to move all the files that are using tmh file, to the same folder...I am not sure why, but now my project builds. There should be a way to fix this. I am not sure if there is anything to do with the "Output directory" that is found under Wpp Tracing->File Options. Right now, I am setting it to a empty folder.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with my driver in Visual Studio 2015. Adding how I got it fixed without having to create a new project.

In your `Project Properties`, navigate to `Wpp Tracing`.

1. In the `General` section, set the value of `Run Wpp Tracing` to `Yes`.
2. In the `Search and Formatting` section, specify the `Function To Generate Trace Messages` to `TraceEvents(LEVEL,FLAGS,MSG,...)`.
3. In the `File Options` section, set `Scan Configuration Data` to `trace.h`.

That should fix it.